# Can't resize the changed image? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If i change the colour of the image and then try to resize, it only resizes the original image. Why is this happening and how do i fix it?

Here is my code:

```
private PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
private PageSettings pgSettings = new PageSettings();
private PrinterSettings prtSettings = new PrinterSettings();

Bitmap myBitmapImage;      // image (bitmap) for some background mountains
Boolean isInvert = false;
Boolean isLOaded = false;
Boolean isGrayscale = false;
Boolean isThreshold = false;
Boolean isResize = false;

OpenFileDialog ofd;
Bitmap bmBack; 

public EditImage()
{
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDoc_PrintPage); 

    InitializeComponent();
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
}

private void EditImage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void EditImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (isLOaded == true)
    {
        Graphics gWindow;   // reference to the graphic surface of this window
        Graphics gBack;     // reference to in-memory surface

        bmBack = new Bitmap(Width, Height);     // bitmap for window surface copy

        gWindow = e.Graphics;   // get our current window's surface
        gBack = Graphics.FromImage(bmBack);     // create surfaces from the bitmaps

        gBack.DrawImage(myBitmapImage, 0, 0, Width, Height);

        if (isInvert == true)
        {
            InvertBitmap(bmBack);
        }
        else if (isGrayscale == true)
        {
            GrayscaleBitmap(bmBack);
        }
        else if (isThreshold == true)
        {
            ThresholdBitmap(bmBack);
        }
        else if (isResize == true)
        {
            bmBack = resizeImage(bmBack, 10, 100);
        }

        gWindow.DrawImage(bmBack, 0, 0);
    }
}
private void toolStripMenuItemLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.Title = "Load Image";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            myBitmapImage = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
            this.Invalidate(); 
        }
    }
    isLOaded = true;
}


private void GrayscaleBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    int numPixels = bmpData.Width * bmp.Height;
    int numBytes = numPixels * 4;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);

    for (int i = 0; i < rgbValues.Length; i += 4)
    {
        byte gray = (byte)(.3 * rgbValues[i + 0]); //blue
        gray += (byte)(.59 * rgbValues[i + 1]); //green
        gray += (byte)(.11 * rgbValues[i + 2]); //red

        rgbValues[i + 0] = gray; //blue
        rgbValues[i + 1] = gray; //green
        rgbValues[i + 2] = gray; //red
    }

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, numBytes);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}

private  Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, 0, 0, width, height);

    return result;
}
```

i also have methods which deal with when the user clicks on a button and sets the bools to appropriate values so that it calls the correct method. The images DO change colour - as intended.. but when i click on resize, i want it to resize the version of the image that has changed colour - not the original image...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of things wrong here:

**resizeImage()**

- You should dispose of the Graphics object that you create here (wrap it in a using() statement)
- Don't call invalidate from here, this function just resizes your image, you invalidate after you've changed your image and your Paint method paints the image which has now changed.
- You should also think about disposing of the sourceBMP right before you return the function if you no longer have any use for it.

**GrayscaleBitmap()**

- This looks right, but again there's no reason to invalidate here.  You should invalidate after you call this method in the calling function.  It makes more sense.

**EditImage_Paint**

- You should not be calling these functions from within your Paint event.  And you should not be creating a new Bitmap and a new Graphics class on each Paint.  This is way more work than necessary.  These functions should only execute when the data needs to be changed based on user input (user clicks a button to apply a grayscale effect).

For what you want to do, you should only need 2 bitmap variables at most.  One to store the original unmodified bitmap in case you want to let the user "Reset" it or to undo any effects (most effects cause permanent data loss, you can't make a grayscale image color again).  And the other to store the bitmap that gets painted.  Each time the user applies an effect, it modifies the 2nd bitmap, and then calls invalidate.

All your Paint function should do is paint the 2nd bitmap:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap; // load from file, do not modify
Bitmap currentBitmap; // when user clicks an effect, modify this bitmap and then Invalidate afterward

private void EditImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    // Draw the currentBitmap centered on the window
    SizeF clientSize = this.ClientSize;

    double zoomRatio = Math.Min(
        clientSize.Width / currentBitmap.Width,
        clientSize.Height / currentBitmap.Height
    );

    SizeF zoomedSize = new SizeF(
        (float)(currentBitmap.Width * zoomRatio),
        (float)(currentBitmap.Height * zoomRatio)
    );

    PointF imageOffset = new PointF(
        (clientSize.Width - zoomedSize.Width) / 2,
        (clientSize.Height - zoomedSize.Height) / 2
    );

    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(currentBitmap, imageOffset.X, imageOffset.Y, zoomedSize.Width, zoomedSize.Height);
}
```

This emulates a simple zoom effect that centers the image on the control and draws it to fit the window.

Comment: Thanks, so i've made all the changes you suggested... except i don't understand how to fix my paint method... can you give me an example of how i would do that?

Comment: Updated with an example of what you can do.

Comment: hmm it seems " RectangleF clientSize = this.ClientSize;" doesn't work... i also can't caste the value.. it says i can't implicity convert type System.Windows.Forms.Form to System.Frawing.RectangleF..

Comment: Oops, supposed to be a SizeF.